# Is there any solid evidence that Sauron was originally called Mairon?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-silmarillion, sauron

It's common knowledge now that Mairon was a smith of Aule and one of the greatest smiths to be known before he became corrupted and commonly known as Sauron. I want to know if anyone knows any specific sources (i.e Tolkien's letters) where Tolkien explicitly states that Mairon was the original name.

Comment: "Common knowledge." Was there a discussion or song at The Prancing Pony's tap-room that I missed?

Comment: I think Thuringwethil used to call him “Uncle May-may?”

Comment: @Mae  to me "proof" would be if achaeologists unearth ruins from a civilization thouands of years before the first known ones, with inscriptions translated as memorials to warriors and lords slain figithing in obedience to "our god Mairon" in holy wars against the evil elves and Dunedain.   But I guess you will have to be content with statements from Tolkien which may or may not be considered canon to various of his published stories.

Comment: In regards to @SillybutTrue's comment: how is 'Mairon' actually pronounced? May-ron, or My-ron? I think that since it is Quenya (right?) the latter is more probable?

Comment: The running joke between Eru and his other created  Ainar was that Sawy “was not Your-ron, he was My-ron.”

Comment: @SillybutTrue Does that make Sauron the disowned Ron that no-one wants?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Per Tolkien's writings on the languages of Middle-earth.

> *Sauron's* original name was *Mairon*, but this was altered after he was suborned by
> *Melkor*. But he continued to call himself *Mairon* the Admirable, or *Tar-mairon* ‘King Excellent’ until after the downfall of Númenor. The Quenya form equivalent to Gorthu was *ñorthus*, *ñorsus*. stem *ñorũr-*.
>
> <sub><sup>[Words, Phrases and Passages in Various Tongues in The Lord of the Rings by J.R.R. Tolkien - Parma Eldalamberon #17](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Parma_Eldalamberon_17)</sup></sub>

This is, to the best of my understanding, the sole place that this name has been mentioned and only became common knowledge after the 2007 publication of Parma Eldalamberon #17. Certainly this was when references were added to the major internet articles about Sauron, for example [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sauron&diff=prev&oldid=162467935)

Comment: "King Excellent" just sounds so weird coming from Tolkien.

Comment: It’s a variant of ancient potentate titles of antiquity: “shah of shahs,” “king of kings,” “great king,” “most high of highs,” et. al.

Comment: @SillybutTrue I’m sure it is.  But it SOUNDS less like Tolkien and something more like, say, Bill and Ted.

Comment: It's funny how so many people know this and yet the source is so obscure.

Comment: @Mae - Because it's on the wiki, probably

Comment: It should also be noted that this quotation is *the only known place* that Tolkien has ever used the name Mairon. So any source that OP has seen mentioning this ultimately derives from this 2007 publication.

Comment: @Valorum Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @suchiuomizu People likewise complain about "Mount Doom" being so literal

Comment: @DavidRoberts - The Mount Doom Tourism Board are petitioning to have it renamed Mount Dome.